# Opening specific Outlook profile with Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

When I run the simple script in PowerShell to open Outlook it works, but when I want to run it via the Task Scheduler it doesn't work.

Script used:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
```

I think the problem is that I login with one account and my Outlook profile is from a different account.
I tried to change the User or Group inside the Task Scheduler, but this also gives me an error that the account is not found.

How can I setup my PowerShell script to ensure I open Outlook with the correct profile?

Comment: You should run the task with the account you want to use for Outlook. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Olaf That is indeed the most convenient way, unfortunately our company has been taken over so our Windows usernames are still on the old company whilst the Outlook profiles are already on the new company. This is causing the issue unfortunately.

Comment: And?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: "*our Windows usernames are still on the old company whilst the Outlook profiles are already on the new company.*" Not sure what this means but it sounds like a temporary issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ProfileName = "Whatever"

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" -ArgumentList "/profile `"$ProfileName`""
```

This might work?